# Ethereum Contract Issue

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-deployment, truffle, remix

I have written a contract `Transfer` and the functions defined in the contract `Transfer` is used in another contract `SecondTransfer`.I have defined a constructor in the contract `Transfer` and initialized values in that constructor.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract Transfer {

        address public userA;
        address public user;
        mapping (address => uint) balances;
        uint value2;

       // constructor

       function Transfer() {
              userA=msg.sender;
              balances[userA]=1000;     
       }

      function sendEther(address user,uint value)returns (bool success){

             if(balances[userA]< value){
                      return false;
             }
             else {
                      balances[userA] -= value;
                      balances[user] += value;
              return true;
             }
   }
   function sendAddressToAddress(address fromuser,address touser)returns      (bool success){
            uint value=balances[fromuser];
            if(value < 0){
                return false;
            }
            else {
                balances[fromuser] -= value;
                balances[touser] += value;
                return true;
            }
  }
  function getBalance(address user) returns (uint _balance){
           return balances[user];
  }
}


 contract SecondTransfer {

 function sendEtherCall(address contractaddr,address user,uint value) returns (bool success) {
      Transfer transfer=Transfer(contractaddr);
      return transfer.sendEther(user,value);
}
function sendAddressToAddressCall(address contractaddr,address fromuser,address touser) returns (bool success) {
      Transfer transfer=Transfer(contractaddr);
      return transfer.sendAddressToAddress(fromuser,touser);
}
function getBalanceCall(address contractaddr,address user) returns (uint _balance) {
      Transfer transfer=Transfer(contractaddr);
      return transfer.getBalance(user);
  }

 }
```

I have tried to run this contract using browser-solidity. I have passed the address of the contract `Transfer` as parameter to the contract `Second Transfer`. But the function `getBalanceCall` returns a VMException error.

Please do help me to rectify the issues. Is there any issues regarding constructor initialization in contract `Transfer`?

I am also trying to create a DApp using Truffle with this contract. In this case how can I pass the address of `Transfer` contract as parameter to `SecondTransfer` contract?

Comment: @ Rob Hitchens  How can i solve these issues

Comment: Please, try not to ask multiple questions in one post. Also, it might be useful to include _which_ VMException you get.

Comment: @ 5chdn Jump Exception

Comment: @5chdn  I am using truffle framework for contract creation.How can i pass the address of 'Transfer' contract as parameter to 'Second Transfer' contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your code it works without exception, i think you passed a wrong contract address.

[image]

Comment: Let me try it once more